# Codeigniter CSRF and Browser Cookie Settings

Tags: php, ajax, cookies, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter and I use database settings for cookies and CRSF is active. My site is using SSL as well. I have been having issue where sometimes my forms and AJAX work fine and sometimes I receive "The action you have requested is not allowed." errors.

I noticed that my form/AJAX submissions work fine in some browsers and not others and I finally figured out it is because of my cookie settings.

I accept cookies in Chrome and not in Firefox and my site works as designed in Chrome.

Is there a way to have my browser setting remain at "do not accept cookies" and still use Codeignier with CSRF? Below are my config settings. As I mentioned my code works just fine in browsers where I accept cookies.

```
$config['sess_driver']             = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name']        = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']         = 0;
$config['sess_save_path']          = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']           = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']     = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '.mysite.com';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;

$config['csrf_protection']   = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name']   = 'msmm_tn';
$config['csrf_cookie_name']  = 'msmm_cn';
$config['csrf_expire']       = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate']   = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```